# Mongoose type Map to Apollo GraphQL Scalar Type

Tags: node.js, mongoose, apollo, mongoose-schema, apollo-server

How to Modular a [Mongoose Map](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps) to a valid type for Apollo-GraphQL Server?

I provided an Example. Basically, a Map is a Key Value list. Is something like this accomplished with interfaces?

### Example:

**Mongoose Schema**

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
   Financials: {
        type: Map,
        of: new Schema({
            q1: {},
            q2: {},
        })
   }
});
```

**As a Document**

```json
{
   "Financials":{
      "2019":{
         "q1":{  },
         "q2":{  }
      },
      "2012":{
         "q1":{  },
         "q2":{  }
      }
   }
}
```

```js
const typeDefs = gql `
      type Financials {
      }
    `
```